# Consolidate Rows with rank

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift, gaps-and-islands

Current:

[image: Current]

When the RNK is 1 then consolidate the ID as shown else if RNK is 0 then keep it as it is .

Please help how to do .

Required:

[image: Required]

Comment: What if there are gaps in the `id` values?  Say, if A101 were missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  However, you really only care about the islands when `rnk = 1`.  So, a convenient way to calculate them is the cumulative sum of `rnk = 0`.  Then the rest is aggregation and combining the ids:

```
select (case when min(id) = max(id) then min(id)
             else min(id) || '-' || max(id)
        end) as id,
       rnk
from (select t.*, sum(1 - rnk) over (order by id) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp, rnk
order by min(id);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fc7811f0fef84aff19ac8a9b2d2864e9) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. You want to group together adjacent rows where `rnk` has value `1`.

Here is an approach using `row_number()` and conditional expressions:

```
select
    case when min(id) <> max(id) then concat(min(id), '-', max(id)) else min(id) end id,
    min(rnk) rnk
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by id) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by rnk order by id) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by case when rnk = 1 then rn1 - rn2 else rn1 + rn2 end
order by min(id)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=59f1eb5924551cfe2e7a9bc64bede3cb)**:

```
id        | rnk
:-------- | --:
A100-A102 |   1
A103      |   0
A104      |   0
A105-A106 |   1
```